How to calculate average stock status in day
Stock status for days is in table
create table stockstatus (
stockdate date not null,  -- date of stock status
product  character(60) not null,  -- product id
status  int not null, -- stock status in end of this day.
constraint primary key ( stockdate, product )
)

How to calculate average stock status in day for given period.
Result table should be
create table AverageStockState (
product c(60) character(60) primary key,
status  int -- average stock status in day in period
)

For example for one product December stock table contains rows
stockdate   status
Dec 1       10
Dec 5       20

Calculation:
Dec 1-4 has status 10
Dec 5-31 has status 20
Average stock status in December is
( 4*10 + ( 31-5+1 ) * 20 ) /31 = 19
So result table should contain product code and value 19 for this product.
Using PostgreSQL 16.2

You can use generate_series() to create a calendar to left join with your data, forward fill the statuses with lag/lead or some other window function, then take a simple avg and group by product, date_trunc('month',stockdate). You can also simplify the calendar away, only adding start/end of month entries and let each window frame lag/lead/ next/previous value for the product and multiply days in between the way you do in your formula.

Where to find sample query which does this in Postgres?

Is your given period always a month? Is there always an entry for the 1st of the month?

Period can be different than month. Average should calculated for number of days in given period. First day in period may not have stock status. In this case there is no entry for first day.

"In this case there is no entry for first day." So what about that missing entry then? What about products that have no entry for the given period? Do you query for a given product or for "all" products? If so, define "all" exactly. Your question is incomplete while corner cases are undefined.

@Andrus There are examples in the doc I linked. I won't be able to post one of mine now but I'm sure if you add some sample data and test cases, you'll get plenty of examples. I think gaps-and-islands, back/forward-filling and window functions are quite popular here

@ErwinBrandstetter If there is no products in source table, they should not appear in result. Result table should contain all products from source table, one row for every product.


date_ranges CTE calculates the current stock_date and the next stockdate based on Lead, as an example only december month is considered, you can adjust as required.

Missing stock dates are then assigned a stock using generate_series in expanded_dates CTE

weighted_sum is calculated by group by and I have used NUMERIC to cast and CEIL to fetch the next integer value.


EDIT : Sample input when stockdate does not start from beginning of month
Fiddle
WITH date_ranges AS (
    SELECT 
        s.product,
        s.stockdate,
        LEAD(s.stockdate) OVER (PARTITION BY s.product ORDER BY s.stockdate) AS next_stockdate,
        s.status
    FROM 
        stockstatus s
),
periods AS (
    SELECT 
        product,
        stockdate AS start_date,
        COALESCE(next_stockdate, '9999-12-31'::date) AS end_date,
        status,
        next_stockdate
    FROM date_ranges
),
daily_status AS (
    SELECT 
        p.product,
        p.start_date,
        p.status,
        p.next_stockdate,
        CASE 
            WHEN p.next_stockdate IS NULL THEN LEAST(p.end_date, '2023-12-31'::date) - GREATEST(p.start_date, '2023-12-01'::date) + 1
            ELSE LEAST(p.end_date, '2023-12-31'::date) - GREATEST(p.start_date, '2023-12-01'::date)
        END AS days_in_period
    FROM periods p
    WHERE p.end_date >= '2023-12-01' AND p.start_date <= '2023-12-31'
),
monthly_status AS (
    SELECT 
        ds.product,
        SUM(ds.days_in_period * ds.status) AS weighted_status_sum,
        COUNT(*) AS total_days_in_period,
        EXTRACT(DAY FROM (DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', MIN(ds.start_date)) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH' - INTERVAL '1 day')) AS days_in_month
    FROM daily_status ds
    GROUP BY ds.product
)
SELECT 
    product,
    weighted_status_sum,
    days_in_month,
    CEIL(weighted_status_sum::NUMERIC / days_in_month::NUMERIC) AS status  
FROM monthly_status
ORDER BY product;

Input data

Output


It looks like if there is no stock status for first day (if first line in input data is not present), it gives incorrect result. How to fix this so it works also if some days in start of period does not have stock status (stock status is 0 in start of period)?

Please provide sample data for: 1. Having no stock status for beginning of period. 2. Period other than for a month. Also provide for each the expected results. Your avg is declared as an integer so what are your rounding rules.

I have added sample input where date starts from 5th december, check the last query in fiddle. Regarding avg , I found @andrus is calculating the next integer , so I used CEIL.
@andrus could you please add more sample input data and edit the question so we can test other scenarios as well
Fiddle => https://dbfiddle.uk/aLJc3-w6

I am not sure why the fiddle link changes everytime, here is the latest fiddle link, I have also edited the same link in the answer
https://dbfiddle.uk/pSeWX5TW

Each time you edit the fiddle, you'll get a new link.

@samhita. Output result is incorrect. Correct result is (5*10+(31-10+1)*20 )/31= 16.  Replaced generate_series first parameter with stockdate, but result is still incorrect. How to fix it?

@Andrus , check it now, There was an issue of how the number of days were calculated, it was adding +1 to all the gaps, now added the condition to add 1 extra day only in the last gap.Updated the code in answer , screenshot and the fiddle link as well.
https://dbfiddle.uk/a-OKxNx9
